# Can wprintf output be properly redirected to UTF-16 on Windows?

Tags: redirect, encoding, utf-16

In a C program I'm using wprintf to print Unicode (UTF-16) text in a Windows console. This works fine, but when the output of the program is redirected to a log file, the log file has a corrupted UTF-16 encoding.
When redirection is done in a Windows Command Prompt, all line breaks are encoded as a narrow ASCII line break (0d0a). When redirection is done in PowerShell, null characters are inserted.

Is it possible to redirect the output to a proper UTF-16 log file?

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main () {

  int prevmode;

  prevmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  fwprintf(stdout,L"one\n");
  fwprintf(stdout,L"two\n");
  fwprintf(stdout,L"three\n");
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), prevmode);


  return 0;
}
```

Redirecting the output in Command Prompt. See the 0d0a which should be 0d00 0a00:

```
c:\test>.\testu16.exe > o.txt

c:\test>xxd o.txt
0000000: 6f00 6e00 6500 0d0a 0074 0077 006f 000d  o.n.e....t.w.o..
0000010: 0a00 7400 6800 7200 6500 6500 0d0a 00    ..t.h.r.e.e....
```

Redirecting the output in PowerShell. See all the 0000 inserted.

```
PS C:\test> .\testu16.exe > p.txt
PS C:\test> xxd p.txt
0000000: fffe 6f00 0000 6e00 0000 6500 0000 0d00  ..o...n...e.....
0000010: 0a00 0000 7400 0000 7700 0000 6f00 0000  ....t...w...o...
0000020: 0d00 0a00 0000 7400 0000 6800 0000 7200  ......t...h...r.
0000030: 0000 6500 0000 6500 0000 0d00 0a00 0000  ..e...e.........
0000040: 0d00 0a00                                ....
```

Comment: Apparently the error in the first example is that `L"\n"` gets output as `0D 0A 00` rather than `0D 00 0A 00`. No idea what the problem in the second example is; it looks a bit like UTF-32, except for the BOM and the newlines. Hm.

Comment: @MrLister if that's the case, then it would be a compiler bug. You have to check the binary to be sure. What compiler are you using, OP?

Comment: [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) gave the correct answer yesterday, but his answer was removed.  [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), if you repost your answer, I will give you the bounty. If not I will post your answer.

Comment: @coladict, I'm using mingw-w64 and Visual Studio 2013. Both give the same result.

Comment: @MrLister, the second example  is double encoded UTF-16. PowerShell modifies the stream. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I got this answer from [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant).
Thanks Hans.

The wrong line breaks are an effect of the buffering of stdout. We need to flush the stream before we set the mode back to the original mode.

```
prevmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
fwprintf(stdout,L"one\n");
fwprintf(stdout,L"two\n");
fwprintf(stdout,L"three\n");
fflush(stdout);               /* flush stream */
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), prevmode);
```

Redirecting the output in Command Prompt (cmd.exe) creates a correct UTF-16 file, without BOM.

```
c:\test>.\testu16 > o.txt

c:\test>xxd o.txt
0000000: 6f00 6e00 6500 0d00 0a00 7400 7700 6f00  o.n.e.....t.w.o.
0000010: 0d00 0a00 7400 6800 7200 6500 6500 0d00  ....t.h.r.e.e...
0000020: 0a00                                     ..
```

In powershell the output is still wrong.

```
PS C:\test> .\testu16 > p.txt
PS C:\test> xxd p.txt
0000000: fffe 6f00 0000 6e00 0000 6500 0000 0d00  ..o...n...e.....
0000010: 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 7400 0000 7700  ..........t...w.
0000020: 0000 6f00 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00  ..o.............
0000030: 0000 7400 0000 6800 0000 7200 0000 6500  ..t...h...r...e.
0000040: 0000 6500 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00  ..e.............
0000050: 0000 0d00 0a00                           ......
```

This is because PowerShell doesn't keep the stream untouched. It tries to interpret it and convert it to UTF-16. It guessed that the input stream encoding was ANSI. PowerShell added an UTF-16 BOM and the rest is double encoded UTF-16. This explains the extra zeros.

Even using out-file and specifying the encoding doesn't help.

```
PS C:\test> .\testu16.exe | out-file p.txt -encoding unicode
PS C:\test> xxd p.txt
0000000: fffe 6f00 0000 6e00 0000 6500 0000 0d00  ..o...n...e.....
0000010: 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 7400 0000 7700  ..........t...w.
0000020: 0000 6f00 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00  ..o.............
0000030: 0000 7400 0000 6800 0000 7200 0000 6500  ..t...h...r...e.
0000040: 0000 6500 0000 0d00 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00  ..e.............
0000050: 0000 0d00 0a00                           ......
```

PowerShell needs to be informed about the encoding, which is done by first printing an UTF-16 BOM:

```
prevmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
fwprintf(stdout, L"\xfeff");  /* UTF-16LE BOM */
fwprintf(stdout,L"one\n");
fwprintf(stdout,L"two\n");
fwprintf(stdout,L"three\n");
fflush(stdout);               /* flush stream */
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), prevmode);
```

Now we get a correct UTF-16 file.

```
PS C:\test> .\testu16 > p.txt
PS C:\test> xxd p.txt
0000000: fffe 6f00 6e00 6500 0d00 0a00 7400 7700  ..o.n.e.....t.w.
0000010: 6f00 0d00 0a00 7400 6800 7200 6500 6500  o.....t.h.r.e.e.
0000020: 0d00 0a00
```

Answer (score 1):

">" will always redirect your console UTF16 as printable "ASCII", even if you put a BOM on your output or use `prevmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);`. I have the same problem with windows7 there is no way to do this with fwprintf.