# How to make git-show export file as UTF-8

Tags: git, character-encoding, git-config

I wanted to view an old version of a file, so I ran

```
git show <commit-sha>:example.less > temp.less
```

to export the old version as `temp.less`. But the exported file ends up having UTF-16 encoding (even thought `example.less` is UTF-8 encoded).

I tried `--encoding=utf-8` and `--encoding=utf8` but neither worked. Besides, I would like to set this in my gitconfig if possible rather than typing it out each time.

---

Windows 10
Git 2.15.0.windows.1

Comment: The ">" prompt means you're on Windows? Then, which Windows? Which git? There are lot of  various gits for Windows. For Win10, try chcp 65001.

Comment: Note that Git itself *stores* a raw byte stream. You can access the raw byte stream at any time using `git cat-file -p <blob-hash-ID>`. It's then up to you to convert it with whatever tools you like. Using `git show` may, or may not, run blobs through various byte-stream-to-encoding converters, depending on your Git version and other details. (Add Git version and OS details to your question as needed.)

Comment: @torek I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](http://%20How%20should%20I%20go%20about%20repairing%20the%20repo) (2.19-rc2), to benefit from the latest bug fixes.

Second, redirect your git show into a file (`git show... >afile`), and view that file in an UTF-8-capable editor (SublimeText, Notepad++, VSCode, ...)
That will be easier than reading it [in an UTF16-CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765469/6309) (meaning `Lucida` font + `CHCP 65001`).

Note: UTF-8 is the default for [`git show --encoding=...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#git-show---encodingltencodinggt).

[Scott H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789708/scott-h) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248592/how-to-make-git-show-export-file-as-utf-8/52251289#comment110379179_52251289):

> I had the same problem in PowerShell but then doing it in `CMD.exe` prompt solved it, even without a special code page (`chcp`) and without specifying `--encoding=utf-8`.
>
> Works with both `git cat-file blob HEAD:file > retrieved` as well as `git show ...`

Comment: I did try redirecting into a file - the problem is that file ends up with UTF-16 encoding for some reason. I know this because when I try to open the file in Brackets it says it's UTF-16 and can't open it. I've edited the question in case this wasn't clear

Comment: @binaryfunt just for testing, did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765469/6309? (`Lucida` font + `Chcp 10000` or `chcp 65001`), as shown in https://superuser.com/a/632800/141

Comment: @binaryfunt ah: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899308/6309 do redirect alone is not a good solution. At the very least `CHCP 65001` is needed before the redirection.

Comment: Tried `> chcp 65001` then git show with and without `--encoding=utf-8`, but it didn't work. Still getting a UTF-16 file. Haven't yet updated git though

Comment: @bin did you follow stackoverflow.com/a/34899308/6309?

Comment: Uh, that doesn't seem to be a followable solution, merely a statement that it's not possible

Comment: @binaryfunt no, I meant: `> chcp 65001` looks like you are trying to redirect a file to `chcp 65001`. That is not what https://superuser.com/a/632800/141 shows. Did you type `chcp 65001` (no `>`), and then try and redirect `git show` to a file?

Comment: Here `>` at the beginning means the cmd (well, powershell) prompt, I didn't type that

Comment: @binaryfunt can you try in a regular CMD session (non-Powershell)?

Comment: I don't see how that will help considering I got the confirmation `Active code page: 65001` after the fact in powershell

Comment: @binaryfunt Just for testing.

Comment: @binaryfunt, @VonC, I had the same problem in PowerShell but then doing it in CMD.exe prompt solved it, even without a special code page (chcp) and without specifying `--encoding=utf-8`. Works with both `git cat-file blob HEAD:file > retrieved` as well as `git show ...`.

Comment: @ScottH Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem in Windows PowerShell that goes away by simply using the CMD terminal instead.

I replicated the behavior in Windows 10 with git version 2.27.0.windows.1. In PowerShell I kept getting a file encoded in UTF-16, even trying tips like changing codepage (with `chcp 65001`) or using `--endoding=utf-8`.

By **simply switching to CMD**, the following kinds of commands worked and produced files in UTF-8:

```
git cat-file blob HEAD:test.txt > retrieved.txt
git show HEAD:test.txt > retrieved.txt
```

While this doesn't solve the issue within PowerShell, at least it narrows down the problem to just PowerShell.